# Importar tabela HTML com base numa URL e preencher um datatable

Tags: c#, html

```
string htmlCode = "";

    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "AvoidError");
        htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://www.site.html");
    }

 HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
 doc.LoadHtml(htmlCode);
 var headers = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr/th");
 DataTable table = new DataTable();
 foreach (HtmlNode header in headers)
 table.Columns.Add(header.InnerText); 
 foreach (var row in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[td]")) 
 table.Rows.Add(row.SelectNodes("td").Select(td => td.InnerText).ToArray());
```

Esse exemplo foi postado em outro tópico no SOen.
Eu n sei se aqui o data table já está preenchido e não sei quais os nomes dos campos da tabela.

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor o seu problema?

Comment: Sim, eu quero importar uma tabela HTML de um site, com base na url e preenhcer um datatable. Uma vez preenchido, quero utilizar meu DTO (objeto transferencia) da minha aplicação para preenhcer outro controle para mostrar os dados na tela. Eu não sei se até aqui nesse código o datatable esta preenchido e não sei como obter os nomes dos campos da tabela. É a primeira vez que utilizo essa abordagem. Sempre utilizo fonte de dados como o Sql para obter os dados.

Comment: Você chegou a testar esse código? Aparentemente ele já está gerando o `DataTable`.

Comment: sim, testei agora e o datatable contem as linhas e colunas, mas não consigo obter o nome dos campos da tabela para implementar o restante.

Comment: Poderia postar o site que está utilizando para retirar esses dados? Isso é, se não tiver problema em postar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não entendi muito bem o seu problema, mas irei modificar o código um pouco para tentar explicar melhor.

Primeiro, o link que você postou [nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/153812/importar-tabela-html-com-base-numa-url-e-preencher-um-datatable?noredirect=1#comment317622_153812) contém mais de uma tabela, então vamos pegar a tabela que deseja pelo `id`.

Seu código final ficará desta forma:

```
           string htmlCode = "";

            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "AvoidError");
                htmlCode = client.DownloadString("http://www.codiceinverso.it/directory-cognomi/cadore.html");
            }

            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(htmlCode);
            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            //Seleciona todas as colunas
            var cabecalhos = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@id='cognomi']/thead/tr/th");
            foreach (HtmlNode col in cabecalhos)
            {
                //Adiciona as colunas
                table.Columns.Add(col.InnerText);
            }

            //Seleciona todas as linhas
            var linhas = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@id='cognomi']/tbody/tr[td]");
            foreach (var row in linhas)
            {
                //Adiciona todas as linhas
                table.Rows.Add(row.SelectNodes("td").Select(td => td.InnerText).ToArray());
            }
```

O `DataTatble` gerado possuirá 2 colunas e 10 linhas, como pode ser visto nas imagens abaixo:

**Colunas:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Linhas:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: aham, é isso ai. obrigado amigo.